# VSCode run ruby file from terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VSCode python extension has a feature to right click and run a file from the terminal. Is there a way that I can use a similar feature to quickly execute a ruby file from the terminal? Perhaps a hot key to start a new terminal session and run the current file within the ruby install directory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can install the [`code-runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) package opening the command palette:

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (Mac)

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (Windows/Linux)

Find and install it:

```
ext install code-runner
```

Then it'll ask you to reload the window, and depending which file type you're working in, you can type the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> keybinding and your file output will be in the output tab.

Comment: I had to use `Ctrl+P` to start the installation. Not sure if it's changed since this was written.

Comment: A lot of time without using vscode, but I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: why it says 'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install Ruby? Anyway, that's a new question @JenuelGanawed.

Comment: Sorry, I replied late ...its fine... I just restarted my laptop and it fixed automatically. @SebastianPalma,, thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Ruby code saved inside .rb extension file
And in the terminal run
ruby file_name.rb

Example:
ankita@ankita-Inspiron-5559:~/Ruby_asignment$ ruby prob_sol1.rb